# mysqldb on python 2.6+ (win32)

Tags: python, mysql

I am currently using python 2.6 and I would like to use the win32 mysqldb module. Unfortunately it seems it needs the 2.5 version of Python. Is there any way to get rid of this mismatch in the version numbers and install mysqldb with python 2.6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are versions of mysqldb for python 2.6, they're just not available on the official site. It took me a while (and unfortunately I lost the link) but you can search google and find people who have compiled and released 2.6 versions of mysqldb for windows x64 and x32.

EDIT:

http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=3108914&forum_id=70460

http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?thread_id=2316047&forum_id=70460

That fourm has a link to versions of mysqldb for Python 2.6

Comment: The links take to http://www.thescotties.com/mysql-python/test/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.6.exe which I tried and was satisfied with on 29th Nov 09

Answer (score 7):

This one has both 32 and 64 versions for 2.6:
http://www.codegood.com/archives/4