# install python Mysql module

Tags: python, mysql

I've just installed python 2.6 on my win7 machine.
Now I tried to install mysqldb. But when run "python setup.py install"

```
 C:\MySQL-python-1.2.3c1>python setup.py install
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
     metadata, options = get_config()
   File "C:\MySQL-python-1.2.3c1\setup_windows.py", line 7, in get_config
     serverKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
     options['registry_key'])
 WindowsError: [Error 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
 (System cannot find the given file)
```

But which file?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I have compiled MySQLdb 1.2.3c1 once with python26, you could find it [here](http://soemin.googlecode.com/files/MySQL-python-1.2.3c1.win32-py2.6.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running from an Administrator Mode command prompt? Also, do you have the MySQL headers available for the compiler to link against?

If you are just an end-user, you will probably find it easier to use a pre-built MySQLdb binary, as compiling in Windows is a pain. Unfortunately the official site still hasn't built against 2.6 yet, but you can download other people's builds. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685869/mysqldb-on-python-2-6) for some links.